# XCode - Create an application without a window and paint directly on screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen, draw

I'm searching now for a while but can't find an entrance…

The application should behave like a ruler app which is always in front of all apps and does not have a window. I want to draw things directly on the screen.

Would be great if someone could help me out with some keywords to search for or a concrete step into.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how do I handle then that the window is always in front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a borderless transparent NSWindow and draw your content inside it. There are many examples for creating those around.

Use [setLevel:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setLevel%3a) to control how the window floats over other windows.